# Can we install django application without source code?

Tags: django

I have a requirement where I need to develop a Point of Sale system.
I want to know if it is possible to install that small point of sale app 
on some machine without source code ?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought I'd mention this for anybody that finds this question useful in the future.

There was a discussion about turning a Django webapp into a local app here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/-VGqvHew35g

They provide some interesting solutions for converting the webapp into a local/desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework. There's no need to install any code on a client machine, since you would access it via a web browser.